# Having scss-lint ignore a particular line

Tags: sass, lint

How do you tell [scss-lint](https://github.com/brigade/scss-lint) to ignore a particular line in a .scss file?

i.e. can you do something like this:

```
.example {
  display: block !important;  // sass-lint: ignore
}
```

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Yep, see [the docs on disabling linters via source](https://github.com/brigade/scss-lint/#disabling-linters-via-source)

```css
// scss-lint:disable ImportantRule
.example {
  display: block !important;
}
// scss-lint:enable ImportantRule
```

Comment: Thanks. For some reason I missed that part of the docs, oops.

Answer (score 12):

Just adding to [steveax's great answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32834986/2427596):

If it's just for the one line, you **can** directly add the comment there and it will only affect that very line.

For instance, consider the following piece of code:

```css
.example {
  display: block !important; // scss-lint:disable ImportantRule
  color: #BADA55 !important;
}
```

Your linter will issue a warning for the `color` line (not complying with `ImportantRule`) but correctly ignore your dirty work with the `display` property.

---

I usually feel it's much clearer to be as specific as possible about the scope of the rule-bending exceptions and always try not to widen these to an entire block of code -- unless it indeed makes sense.