# Have sass-lint ignore a certain line?

Tags: sass, gulp, gulp-sass

I'm using *sass*-lint with Gulp. How can I disable warnings for a particular style in my sass from the lint console output?

I've found a similar question but I'm using **sass**-lint, not **scss**-lint: 
[Having scss-lint ignore a particular line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32833542/having-scss-lint-ignore-a-particular-line)

This is the one I'm using: https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-sass-lint

I've tried a few variations based off of the ***scss***-lint project:

```
// scss-lint:disable ImportantRule
// sass-lint:disable ImportantRule
// sass-lint:disable no-important
```

Just to be clear, I want to disable warnings for a specific style in my SASS, not globally. I will use this when the thing triggering the warning is intentional. For instance I might set multiple background styles so one can be a fallback for older browsers. But currently this is triggering the no-duplicate-properties warning.

Answer (score 107, accepted):

### Disabling through comments

**Update per December 2016** according to [the docs](https://github.com/sasstools/sass-lint#disabling-linters-via-source) this will now be possible using this syntax:

> **Disable more than 1 rule for entire file**
>
> ```
> // sass-lint:disable border-zero, quotes
>
> p {
>   border: none; // No lint reported
>   content: "hello"; // No lint reported
> }
> ```
>
> **Disable a rule for a single line**
>
> ```
> p {
>   border: none; // sass-lint:disable-line border-zero
> }
> ```
>
> **Disable all lints within a block (and all contained blocks)**
>
> ```
> p {
>   // sass-lint:disable-block border-zero
>   border: none; // No result reported
> }
> ```

<sup>New info courtesy of commenter @IanRoutledge.</sup>

**However, *before***, if you wanted to disable certain rules, but only for specific code blocks and/or pieces of the code. *As far as I can [tell](https://github.com/sasstools/sass-lint/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=disable)* from the underlying source code it would *not* be possible with sass-lint. I've tried a few other searches as well, and skimmed the code base in general, but found no hint that the feature you're looking for exists.

For comparison, [this query for the scss-lint source code](https://github.com/brigade/scss-lint/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=disable) clearly shows it *is* implemented there, in a fashion that doesn't seem to have an analogous solution in the lib you are using.

### Disabling through yml configs

You *can* disable rules in general though. You need to have a `.sass-lint.yml` file to disable warnings.

Suppose you have this `gulpfile.js`:

```
'use strict';

var gulp = require('gulp'),
    sassLint = require('gulp-sass-lint');

gulp.task('default', [], function() {
  gulp.src('sass/*.scss')
    .pipe(sassLint())
    .pipe(sassLint.format())
    .pipe(sassLint.failOnError());
});
```

And this `package.json`:

```
{
  "devDependencies": {
    "gulp": "^3.9.0",
    "gulp-sass": "^2.1.1",
    "gulp-sass-lint": "^1.1.1"
  }
}
```

Running on this `styles.scss` file:

```
div { dsply: block; }
```

You get this output:

```
[23:53:33] Using gulpfile D:\experiments\myfolder\gulpfile.js
[23:53:33] Starting 'default'...
[23:53:33] Finished 'default' after 8.84 ms

sass\styles.scss
  1:7   warning  Property `dsply` appears to be spelled incorrectly  no-misspelled-properties
  1:21  warning  Files must end with a new line                      final-newline

??? 2 problems (0 errors, 2 warnings)
```

Now if you add a `.sass-lint.yml` file next to the gulpfile, with this content:

```
rules:
  no-misspelled-properties: 0
```

You'll instead see:

```
[23:54:56] Using gulpfile D:\experiments\myfolder\gulpfile.js
[23:54:56] Starting 'default'...
[23:54:56] Finished 'default' after 9.32 ms

sass\styles.scss
  1:21  warning  Files must end with a new line  final-newline

??? 1 problem (0 errors, 1 warning)
```

One of the warnings is now ignored.

[The sass-lint readme.md](https://github.com/sasstools/sass-lint/blob/develop/README.md) links to [the apparent default config](https://github.com/sasstools/sass-lint/blob/master/lib/config/sass-lint.yml) which has some more examples.

Comment: I need to disable warnings for a particular style in my SASS for when the thing that is triggering the error is actually intentional. I don't want to disable all warnings. Ive updated my question to make it clearer.

Comment: Point taken. Thinking I'll leave my answer here for others that land here through Googling, might be of use to someone.

Comment: @Evans I've updated my answer. As far as I can tell what you want is just not possible with sass-lint. If another answer proves me wrong please ping me so I can remove that assumption from my own answer.

Comment: v1.10.1 now has support for this, https://github.com/sasstools/sass-lint#disabling-linters-via-source

Comment: Thanks @IanRoutledge. This thread gets a decent amount of views so I've slipstreamed the info you've provided in my answer. Feel free to suggest further edits to improve it.

Answer (score 11):

As of sass-lint 1.10.0 it's been possible to disable sass-lint rules via source comments

Below are the different permutations of this, intentionally almost identical to the scss-lint way before.

**Disable a rule for the entire file**

```
// sass-lint:disable border-zero
p {
  border: none; // No lint reported
}
```

**Disable more than 1 rule**

```
// sass-lint:disable border-zero, quotes
p {
  border: none; // No lint reported
  content: "hello"; // No lint reported
}
```

#### Disable a rule for a single line

```
p {
  border: none; // sass-lint:disable-line border-zero
}
```

#### Disable all lints within a block (and all contained blocks)

```
p {
  // sass-lint:disable-block border-zero
  border: none; // No result reported
}

a {
  border: none; // Failing result reported
}
```

#### Disable and enable again

```
// sass-lint:disable border-zero
p {
  border: none; // No result reported
}
// sass-lint:enable border-zero

a {
  border: none; // Failing result reported
}
```

#### Disable/enable all linters

```
// sass-lint:disable-all
p {
  border: none; // No result reported
}
// sass-lint:enable-all

a {
  border: none; // Failing result reported
}
```

The sass-lint [readme](https://github.com/sasstools/sass-lint#disabling-linters-via-source) includes all of the details and the [docs](https://github.com/sasstools/sass-lint/blob/develop/docs/toggle-rules-in-src.md) have been updated too.

The grunt, gulp and atom plugins have all been updated too to require v1.10 and above so a quick reinstall of these or an update and you'll be ready to go.

We're sorry it took so long to come out but we had to fix a few issues in our AST before we were confident of them being useful.

Comment: I tried // sass-lint:disable-all, // sass-lint:disable/enable [rule], as you suggested - they all work like magic, thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Disabling linting rules for specific lines is supported as of sass-lint 1.10.

https://github.com/sasstools/sass-lint#disabling-linters-via-source

<strike>As yet sass-lint does not support disabling rules on a per-file or per-line basis. They have a [long-standing GitHub issue](https://github.com/sasstools/sass-lint/issues/70) tracking the feature.</strike>

Comment: v1.10.1 now has support for this, https://github.com/sasstools/sass-lint#disabling-linters-via-source

Answer (score 0):

Gotcha.

First, here's the listing of rules for sass-lint:

https://github.com/sasstools/sass-lint/tree/develop/lib/rules

Next, you can set an option for the rule you want:

```
rule:
    severity: 0
```

0 = nothing written

1 = warning

2 = error

Is this what you needed?

Comment: I need to ignore certain styles, not set global rules. Eg the duplicate style warning should normal be displayed, however for a particular single instance in my SASS it's intentional and i need to disable the warning for this instance only.