# Disable scss.lint rule for one file in VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, scss-lint

I'm using VS Code settings.json to add scss.lint rules. I've enabled the ImportantRule but I want to turn it off for one file.

[This SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35142043/3935156) says how to do it for scss-lint but it isn't working for me in VS Code.

Is there a way to do this in VS Code?

Answer (score 1):

I am looking for this too, but after some thought, I think that it does not make much sense to put VSCode specific tags inside the source code.

I **love** VS Code, but what if your other people in the project doesn't use VSCode? What if he/she uses Sublime, Atom or Brackets? Do they need to add an `ignore-next-line` for their IDE as well?

It will soon get very ridiculous.

Would love to hear other peoples thoughts on this!